# How to sample dynamic data

Tags: statistics, sampling

I don know math and statistics.I want to divide data into 2 sets . Set#1 contain short values and Set#2 contain large values.Data is coming from stream and i don know the values in advance. How can i decide short and long values. For example Data is=1,1,1,2,2,100 then i can have set1={1,2,2,2,2} and set2={100} Or data can be 1,2,3,4,4 then set1={1,2} set2={3,4,4}
I don know the domain name of this problem . What i should google . What i should learn so that i can sample data on the basis of particular formula or pattern.

Comment: This sounds like an unsupervised learning problem. Perhaps k-means clustering would work? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: Yes my problem seems to be K-means clustering.

Comment: yes it is... how ca I vote you?

Comment: The only issue here might be streaming versus batch. I think k-means prefers batch. I'm not sure how you could adapt it to streaming, except to collect data for a while, process, collect, process, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Try googling confidence banding for time series.  This will give you a way of determining whether a value is large based on a confidence level (say $90\%$).  You'll want to look up linear regression as well, in order to perform this style of analysis.  I don't have the time to write it all out right now; I'll try to come back later when I have more time.

Comment: Thanks! I start searching now. But i am also waiting for your further help

Comment: What i have learn after searching i found that If you are interested in whether one variable differs among possible groups, for instance,
then regression isn’t necessarily the best way to answer that question. Often you can find
your answer by doing a t-test or an ANOVA.

Comment: I strongly disagree, especially in your case when you only have 2 groups, high and low and you have no independent variables; the best unbiased sampling grouping you can do is above average or below average, which is exactly a linear regression problem.

Comment: Also, t-test and ANOVA are regression analyses.